# Little or too little

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, noun-phrases

I wonder if there are any differences between  in the following sentences
in terms of meaning.

> I have little money to buy a new car.
>
> I have too little money to buy a new car.

As far as I know, both convey a meaning that it is " not enough" and using "too" makes  the situation a bit more emphasizing.

Comment: The second is better. The first sounds like you might have quite a lot of money for other things.

Comment: They have different meanings. The first implies you don’t have a lot of money to buy a car, but you can still buy *some kind of* car. The second sentences says your finances *prevent you from buying any car at all*.

Comment: Also be aware that "I have **a** little money to buy a new car"" exists

Comment: @FeliniusRex Does "I have a little money to buy A new car" have a meaning that "The first implies you don’t have a lot of money to buy a car, but you can still buy some kind of car."

Comment: Is it correct : Both has a meaning that you do not have enough money to buy a car.  The first sentence can imply you can have some money which is enough to buy other things but not a car. However, the second sentence implies that you can not buy almost anything.

Comment: is it correct : you can just say " I have little money" or "I have too little money". In this case, both has almost the same meaning.

Comment: @Mrt - No. Please re-read what I said. They have different meanings.

Comment: @FeliniusRex but then what is the difference between "I have a little money to buy a car" and " I have little money to buy a car". I thought " I have a little money" means you do not have much money but you can still afford some kind of car.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is in what is implied.

> I have little money to buy a car

suggests something like *so I might not be able to find one I can afford*, or *so it won't be a very good one*.

> I have too little money to buy a car

implies *there is no chance I will find one I can afford*.

The third option, mentioned in the comments,

> I have a little money to buy a car

doesn't have these negative implications, so it might be followed by something like *so I'm going to see what I can find*.

As andyman says, English speakers are much more likely to say *not much* and *not enough* than *little* and *too little*.

Answer (score 0):

The second choice is the better, but I would not recommend using either, as you could rephrase your sentence to sound better by saying "I don't have enough money to buy a car." Sometimes restructuring a sentence can make it sound much better than making small changes.