# A bit too much, could i use "a bit too little" as the opposite?

Tags: phrases

Could i use "a bit too little" as the opposite of a bit too much? Or I'm wrong? Thanks!

Comment: "**Not quite enough**" is the usual expression. Or perhaps "rather too little." We might say a child is "a bit too little" to go on a  fairground ride.

Comment: See also "[too little money](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/281150/little-or-too-little)"

Comment: It's possible.  [You can find examples in Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+bit+too+little%22)